# Showing that the Bessel integral representation solves the Bessel function

Tags: integration, proof-explanation, special-functions, bessel-functions

Is there a simple way to show the following: $\int_0^\pi \cos(x\sin(\theta)) \ d\theta$ satisfies $x^2y''+xy'+x^2y=0$.

I know this is the integral representation of the Bessel function, I am wondering if there is a simple method to prove this, without making use that the integral is the integral representation of the Bessel function.

Answer (score 8):

With $y=\int_0^{\pi} \cos{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta $,
$$ y' = -\int_0^{\pi} \sin{\theta}\sin{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta \\
y''= -\int_0^{\pi} \sin^2{\theta}\cos{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta =  - y + \int_0^{\pi} \cos^2{\theta} \cos{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta . $$
Multiplying by $x^2$ and integrating by parts, we therefore have
$$ \begin{align}
x^2(y''+y) &= \int_0^{\pi} (x\cos{\theta})^2 \cos{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta \\
&= [ x\cos{\theta} \sin{(x\sin{\theta})} ]_0^{\pi} + \int_0^{\pi} x \sin{\theta} \sin{(x\sin{\theta})} \, d\theta \\
&= 0 - 0 - xy',
\end{align} $$
as required.

Comment: When doing the integration by parts, isn't there a factor of $2$ in the second term because of the derivative of $\cos^2(\theta)$??

Comment: No, I’m integrating $x\cos{\theta} \cos{(x\sin{\theta})}$, which leaves only $x\cos{\theta}$ to differentiate.